# How do I go about writing a loop that's supposed to be boolean yet the answer can be an integer using JOptionPane?

Tags: java, while-loop, joptionpane

How do I go about writing a loop that's supposed to be boolean, yet the answer can be an integer using `JOptionPane`?

> - `boolean promptMenu( int menu )`
>
>   - This will represent the core of your code.
>   - Should be in the body of a loop inside `main()`.
>   - Returns true if it should continue running.
>   - Returns false if it is time to quit.
>   - Notice that `promptMenu` takes in an `int` parameter:
>       0 - Prints the Main Menu.

So far this is what I got:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class BankSystem {

    //Fields
    static boolean question = true;
    static String q ;
    static int qt;

    //Methods
    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        while(question = true)
        {
            promptMenu (qt) ;
        }
    }

    static int promptMenu( int qt )
    {
        q = JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("Gen's Bank" + "\n \n Print main menu? 0-> YES\n\n") ;
        qt = Integer.parseInt(q);

        if (qt != 0)
        {
            question = false;
        }

        return (qt);
    }

}
```

If you press anything that isn't 0 it still loops. Any Suggestions would help.

Answer (score 2):

Read the question carefully.  The question asks you for a method:

```
boolean promptMenu( int menu )
```

What you have written is a different method:

```
int promptMenu( int menu )
```

You instructor wants you to write a method returning a `boolean` but you are writing a method that returns an `int`.  You are not answering the question that was asked.

To return a `boolean` you need:

```
return true;

return false;
```

or something like:

```
boolean boolVar;
boolVar = // Your code here.
return boolVar;
```

Answer (score 0):

What you got:

```
public static void main(String[]args)
{
    while(question = true)
    {
        promptMenu (qt) ;
    }
}
```

What you need:

```
public static void main(String[]args)
{
    while(question == true)
    {
        promptMenu (qt) ;
    }
}
```

If you want to check conditions you have to use one of the following parameters (<, <=, >, >=, !=, ==). One single **=** is used to assign values to a variable.